# Is the following principle the right for autobahn python?

Tags: python, c, html, websocket, autobahn

I'm researching about WebSockets atm and just found Autobahn with `Autobahn|Python`.
I'm not sure that I understand the function of that toolset (?) correctly.

My intention is to use a `WebSocket-Server` for communication between a `C` program and a HTML client.

The idea is to let the `C` program connect via `WebSocket` to the Server and send the calculation progress of the `C` program to every HTML client that is connected to that `WebSocket-Server`.

Am I able to write a `WebSocket` Server with `Autobahn|Python` and then connect with an `HTML5-client` and a `C` program client?

Answer (score 1):

Autobahn|Python provides both a WebSocket implementation for Python and an implementation for a client for the WAMP protocol on top of that.

You can use the WebSocket part on its own to implement your WebSocket server.